# Using FB API V1 with new Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to search in public Facebook Posts.
So, i check my querys using the Graph-Explore-Tool to see whats happen.

```
search?q=%23wm2014
```

Switching the Version to 1.0 in top of the Page returns some postings.
So, i created a new FB App, and send my request (via post) to the server.
I always get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 11
  }
}
```

So, i used the Endpoint: https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/
but i recived still the same error.

Finaly i used an old FB App i created (october 2013) and used this App-ID and App-Secret vor the access_token-Parameter and: suprise suprise! it works.

Are there hidden settings in the FB App Settings, to define, witch API should be used?

Thanks for your help.
S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps created after April 2014 will only be able to use v2.0

So if you need to use v1.0 (which will only be possible until April 2015), you have to use an old App.

Using the v1.0 endpoint does not really make sense, but the v2.0 endpoint is there to force older Apps to use the new version already.

> For apps created on or after April 30th 2014, making API calls without specifying a version number is equivalent to calling v2.0 of the API. These apps won't be able to call v1.0 of the API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: Thanks. I find it out by myself. But yes. Thats the online worklfow i found. Thank you @lushn.